# Multiple dots (points) separator

Tags: macos, awk

Any equivalent to
`echo "(one)  ...  (two)" |awk -F  "\.\.\." '{print $2}' # works in linux`

which works on mac os

`echo "(one)  ...  (two)" |awk -F  " ... " '{print $2}' # 'works' when we add spaces` 
or use single dot separator 
`echo "(one)  ...  (two)" |awk -F  "\." '{print $4}'`
but with more than one dot (or dot with single space) fails (gives different interpretations)?

try `echo "(one)  ...  (two)" |awk -F  " \." '{print $2}'` or `echo "(one)  ...  (two)" |awk -F  "\. " '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a regex in field separator, escaping the special character with one back slash doesn't really mean anything special. You'll have to do:

```
$ echo "(one)  ...  (two)" | awk -F  "\\\.\\\.\\\." '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i " is "$i}' | cat -ve
$1 is (one)  $
$2 is   (two)$
```

The better way to do is put the special character in a character class to consider it literal.

```
$ echo "(one)  ...  (two)" | awk -F  "[.]{3}" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i " is "$i}' | cat -ve
$1 is (one)  $
$2 is   (two)$
```

Comment: Or you can use `-F '\\.\\.\\.'`